# Obj-C - if statement on array with images

Tags: ios, objective-c

I've got an array which looks like this:

```
contentImages = @[@"img1.png", @"img2.png", @"img3.png"];
```

The images are displayed in a storyboard and the user can interact with them in a slideshow.

But I want to check which image is currently shown and change a label to a custom text for that image only. So let's say image 1 will display "Lorem ipsum", whilst image 2 will display "Ipsum lorem" etc etc.

Please help me!
Thanks :)

Comment: What language is this?

Comment: Please note that this has nothing to do with the `xcode` IDE.

Answer (score 3):

You should maintain a dictionary with 2 keys: "imageName" and "description". And this dictionary should be in the mainArray.

Now as per the index of the current visible slide you can fetch the object(dictionary) from the array.

Once you get the dictionary you can know the name of the image and its description.

For example:

```
[
  { "imgName":"img1.png", "description":"Desc-1" },
  { "imgName":"img2.png", "description":"Desc-2" },
  { "imgName":"img3.png", "description":"Desc-3" }
]
```

Copy this in a TextEdit and save file as images.json . Add this json file in your application bundle. Load this json runtime in your contentImages Array. Now as per the index of your page controller you can fetch dictionary from your contentImages array and use the values for keys "imageName" and "description".

Hope this helps.

Comment: I would actually mantain only one array with objects that have `imageName` and `description` as properties.

Comment: @Sulthan I believe that's exactly what this answer is suggesting.

Comment: @trojanfoe I wouldn't use a dictionary. Also I thought the question was originally suggesting 2 arrays but maybe I was reading wrong.

Comment: Hmm, I tried but didn't get it to work. You might find the problem: http://pastebin.com/76gS01uz

The commented code is the code I've tried with and of course when I did so, I commented the old array.

Comment: [
     {
  "imgName":"img1.png",
  "description":"Desc-1"
     },
     {
  "imgName":"img2.png",
  "description":"Desc-2"
     },
     {
  "imgName":"img3.png",
  "description":"Desc-3"
     }
    ]

Copy this in a TextEdit and save file as images.json . Add this json file in your application bundle. Load this json runtime in your contentImages Array. Now as per the index of your page controller you can fetch dictionary from your contentImages array and use the values for keys "imageName" and "description".

Comment: @dsiddhpura How would you write that in code using my provided code? http://pastebin.com/ArQpuKru

Answer (score 0):

One of the simplest way would be to create `NSDictionary` with key as image name and value as label. You can then use your `contentImages` structure to fetch the image and this new `NSDictionary` to fetch the label text.

Comment: How would you maintain *order*?

Comment: @trojanfoe Yes, you are right. I forgot to give reference to OP' existing structure. Corrected post.